# notice in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

what is the problem if i got this notice saying:

**Notice**:  Undefined index:  8 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\wesm\intranet\plugins\survey_manager\index.php** on line **80**

i'm using the jquery autocomplete..

here is some of my code for javascript in which the error occurred:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var intranetUsers = ["<?php echo $content[0].' ", "';
        $num = 1;
        while($num != $getInranetUserCount['num']){
            echo $content[$num].'" , "';
            $num = $num + 1;
        }
            echo $content[$getInranetUserCount['num']];
    ?>"];


</script>
```

I've already use that code in some module and it works I don't know why it doesn't work this time.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: `Undefined index: 8 in` <-- Is your $content variable perhaps having an index that's going past the size of the array?

Comment: Try setting $num < $getInranetUserCount['num']

Comment: yup i'm mixing php and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var intranetUsers = ["<?php echo $content[0].' ", "';
```

Would definitely error out. Without knowing the value of either $content or $getInranetUserCount, I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Perhaps a better question would be explaining what you're trying to do than just giving a small snippet that none of us are going to understand without context.

Comment: as i've said i already use that script in some module and it works correctly.
it is not an error since it is inside the php file..

Comment: Gotcha, I can see I missed the single quotes originally. My apologies. What spits out if you do a var_dump($content);?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$content` array is most likely missing an entry for `$num == 8`. You'll find the source of your problem elsewhere in your application.

In general, it's a bad idea to inline PHP with Javascript this way. Consider at the very least breaking it up:

```
<?php
// Start capturing output to buffer
ob_start();
// Create string
echo $content[0].' ", "';
$num = 1;
while($num != $getInranetUserCount['num']){
    echo $content[$num].'" , "';
    $num = $num + 1;
}
echo $content[$getInranetUserCount['num']];
// Get output from buffer
$out = ob_get_contents();
// End buffering
ob_end_clean();
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var intranetUsers = ["<?php echo $out ?>"];
</script>
```

Comment: It won't fix the problem you've got, it'll just make it easier to read. That's not a bad idea for when you post to StackOverflow about a "jQuery" problem that has almost nothing to do with JavaScript.